# For doing iPhone image processing, should I start from the View-based or OpenGL ES template?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image, image-processing, opengl-es

If I want to build an iPhone application that does image processing, should I start from the View-based Application project template or the OpenGL ES Application one?  Can image processing be done in an application built using the View-based Application project template?

Comment: What does OpenGL or a view-based application have to do with image processing?

Image-processing generally means doing calculations on an image. So this only depends on the data structure you have your image stored in. You can show it however you like, using OpenGL or a View-based application

Comment: @evident - You may wish to use OpenGL ES 2.0 shaders to process the image on the GPU, rather than the CPU.  Programmable GPUs aren't only useful for displaying things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As always, it doesn't really matter what template you choose when you start a new iPhone application project.  These templates don't commit you to a particular development track, so you can always add the elements you need later on.

If you start with a View-based application, you can easily add an OpenGL ES layer and its hosting view later.  Likewise, if you start from the OpenGL ES template, you can remove the UIView that hosts the OpenGL ES layer if you don't need it.

There's probably a slight advantage in starting with the OpenGL ES template, because it's easier to pull things out than add then in, but there isn't that much of an advantage in going that way.

The bigger question is: should you do your image processing on the GPU or CPU?  That will dictate whether or not you need to use OpenGL ES.  Using the GPU can give you a significant performance boost (from 14X - 28X [in my measurements](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios)), but it adds some complexity.  Apple has a great OpenGL ES image processing example in their [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/index.html) sample, and I have a sample application that uses OpenGL ES 2.0 programmable shaders [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ColorTracking.zip).  Otherwise, you can do pixel manipulation on raw data or using Core Graphics for CPU-based image processing without involving OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible with a View based application to process images.